# On a query complexity for threshold functions

Tags: boolean-functions, query-complexity

We have a fixed integer $k$ from  $\{0,q,\dots,2^n\}$ and we want to find whether a very long string $u\in\{0,1\}^{2^n}$ in $2^n$ variables is accepted by the "$k$-threshold function" which is $T_k(u)=1\iff |u|>k$.

I have access to a black box $\mathcal H$ which can compute a particular symmetric function $h$ in $2^n$ variables. For each query I can set arbitrary coordinates $i_1,\dots,i_t\in\{1,\dots,2^n\}$ to the black box $\mathcal H$ where $t\in\{0,1,\dots,2^n\}$ is variable. The black box would return $h(u_{i_1},\dots,u_{i_t},0,\dots,0)\in\{0,1\}$. I am interested in the number of such queries necessary.

> The question is given $h$ can we tell if we have $O(n^c)$ randomized query complexity? Are there specific tools for this problem (might be using communication complexity)?

There are $h$ with $O(1)$ deterministic query complexity. Example $h=T_k$.

In literature we usually take $h=u_i$ for some coordinate $u_i$ (classical randomized query complexity) and $h=u_{i_1}\oplus\dots\oplus u_{i_t}$ (randomized parity query complexity).

Comment: Not entirely I parse the question correctly: you want an answer as a function of $h$? (Characterizing/finding which $h$'s lead to small randomized query complexity)